# Cakephp3: How to search data in paginate with contain condition?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables name are miscellaneous and users. In miscellaneous table has driver_id and vendor_id. Both id in users table with name id column. Here is my sample code.

src/Model/Table/Miscellaneous.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

    class MiscellaneousTable extends Table {

        public function initialize(array $config) {
            $this->table('miscellaneous');
            $this->displayField('name');
            $this->primaryKey('id');

            $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
            $this->belongsTo('Vendors', [
                'foreignKey' => 'vendor_id',
                'className' => 'users',
                'joinType' => 'left'
            ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Drivers', [
                'foreignKey' => 'driver_id',
                'className' => 'users',
                'joinType' => 'left'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I want search in vendor name and driver name. Here is my paginate conditions:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['vendor']['name'])) {
   $vendor_name = $this->request->data['vendor']['name'];
}
if (!empty($this->request->data['driver']['name'])) {
    $driver_name = $this->request->data['driver']['name'];
}
$miscellaneous = $this->paginate($this->Miscellaneous, ['contain' => ['Drivers' => function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
    return $q->where(['Drivers.name LIKE ' => '%'.$driver_name.'%']);
    }, 'Vendors' => function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
    return $q->where(['Vendors.name LIKE ' => '%'.$vendor_name.'%']);
    }], 'conditions' => $con, 'order' => ['Miscellaneous.id' => 'DESC']]);
```

But it shows nothing. Please help me to find the correct solutions.
It works without condition of vendor and driver name.

Comment: Closures dont inherit parent scope, so you need to define what variables you want to use inside them. You can do this with `use` directive, eg, `function (Query $q) use ($driver_name) {...}`

Comment: Use https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search and read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `belongTo` associations (which Cake can handle with normal Joins) i often use following code-snippet:

```
<?PHP
  $whereArray = [];
  if (!empty($this->request->data['vendor']['name'])) {
    $whereArray[] = ['Vendors.name LIKE ' => '%'.$this->request->data['vendor']['name'].'%'];
  }
  if (!empty($this->request->data['driver']['name'])) {
    $whereArray[] = ['Drivers.name LIKE ' => '%'.$this->request->data['driver']['name'].'%'];
  }
  $miscellaneous = $this->paginate($this->Miscellaneous->find('all', ['contain' => ['Vendors', 'Drivers']])->where($whereArray)->order(['Miscellaneous.id' => 'DESC']);

?>
```

Annotation: I often use "all" as finder because i need the full records also in lists...